# Why psycopg2 is not able to install in a virtual environment?

Tags: 20.04, python, pip, virtualenv

Just installed ubuntu20.04.

Installed python3.10 by

```
sudo apt install python3.10
```

Then created virtualenv

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv -p python3.10 venv
```

Now I'm trying to install requirement for my project. The only one issue I got was with distutils. But I typed smth like

```
sudo apt install python3.10-distutils
```

And it's gone.
I have requirements list like

- amqp==5.0.6
- asgiref==3.4.1
- billiard==3.6.4.0
- celery==5.1.2
- certifi==2021.5.30
- charset-normalizer==2.0.6
- click==7.1.2
- click-didyoumean==0.0.3
- click-plugins==1.1.1
- click-repl==0.2.0
- dj-database-url==0.5.0
- Django==3.2.7
- django-celery-beat==2.2.1
- django-celery-results==2.2.0
- django-heroku==0.3.1
- django-redis==5.0.0
- django-timezone-field==4.2.1
- gunicorn==20.1.0
- idna==3.2
- kombu==5.1.0
- prompt-toolkit==3.0.20
- psycopg2==2.9.1
- python-crontab==2.5.1
- python-dateutil==2.8.2
- python-dotenv==0.19.0
- pytz==2021.1
- redis==3.5.3
- requests==2.26.0
- six==1.16.0
- sqlparse==0.4.2
- urllib3==1.26.6
- vine==5.0.0
- wcwidth==0.2.5
- whitenoise==5.3.0

They all installed except of psycopg2.
When I type (in activated virtualenv)

```
pip install psycopg2==2.9.1
```

And getting this
error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1

Comment: What are the actual errors and commands you see and type. This long list of file names means nothing. The whole question could use some clarity.

Comment: @David I putted this list to show that other modules are frelly installed. The only one issue is with the psycopg2.
When i type
pip install psycopg2
I'm getting mentioned error:
 error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1

Comment: "x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc" would have me believe you are missing headers. is `sudo apt install python3.10-dev` a fix?

Comment: @Rinzwind Nope. I saw this site and typed all mentioned commands. 
https://linuxnetmag.com/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved with

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

This will not require any C code compilation